# Enter key in a while loop

Tags: c, enter, getchar

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    char word[100];

    while (word != "hello") {

        system("clear");

        printf("\nSay hello to me : ");

        scanf(" %s", word);
    }

    printf("congrats, you made it !");

    return 0;
}
```

In this code : if i enter anything but hello, the loop continue. However, entering the ENTER key will not loop again, it will just add a line.

I read somewhere that using getchar() might help but I'm kinda new to the C developpement and I'm stuck here searching for hours how to make it works.

**EDIT 0 :**

Removed

```
while (word != "hello")
char word[100];
scanf(" %s", word);
```

Added

```
#include <string.h>
while (strcmp(word, "hello") != 0)
char word[100] = {0}; 
fgets(word, 6, stdin);
```

**EDIT 1 :**

I tried to include in my code something like that

```
fgets(word, 6, NULL);
```

But it got me a segmentation fault.

**EDIT 2 : **

The correct working input is :

```
fgets(word, 6, stdin);
```

So it worked, but adding more than 6 character to the question like :

```
Say hello to me : hello from the inside
```

Will just print :

```
Say hello to me :
Say hello to me :
```

So I just modified the function like that :

```
fgets(word, 100, stdin);
```

But now it will not get me any input to work

Comment: The one line per line style again :) ... I wonder where does it come from if it's so ugly?

Comment: It doesn't look like this code puts anything into "word".  Shouldn't your scanf use word and not mot?  And mot isn't defined either.

Comment: scanf wants to read at leas one non-whitespace character.

Comment: yes I was just translating my code from french to english

Comment: So you suggest I should use something better than scanf ?

Comment: `word != "hello"` compares two addresses.

Comment: You should use strcmp to compare strings not != operator

Comment: You need `strcmp` to compare string in C.

Comment: You're doing a pointer comparison with `word != "hello"` which is guaranteed to be false.  What you want instead is `strcmp(word, "hello") != 0`

Comment: read a *whole line*.

Comment: Please don't modify the question to apply any suggested changes, as that invalidates the answers.  Instead, comment on whether the changes worked or not.

Comment: It was just minors mistakes as I firstly used char but then changed to try with the word hello so I forgot to use string instead but it doesn't change my question at all. I'm still trying to find how to take enter key behavior in count in my while loop

Comment: Gradiuss, [@dbush](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34911501/2410359) Answer well answer this post's concerns. The original post did not have minor, but major mistakes.   Re-writing the post to a new question creates a moving target. Better to learn from this post, form a new question (add a link to this post) and move forward.

Comment: Concerning "entering the ENTER key will not loop again", do not use `scanf(" %s",...`.  An answer explains "The %s format specifier already ignores leading whitespace."  Instead use `fgets()`.

Comment: Thanks @chux it worked (kind of), I struggled but I found online that for direct keyboard input I should use stdin instead of NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34911501/2410359) well answered OP initial concerns.

OP is now using `fgets(word, 100, stdin);` and types in <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  `word[]` is then filled with `"hello\n"` and this does not pass `strcmp(word, "hello") != 0`.

Solution: strip final `'\n'`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int main() {
  char word[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };

  while (strcmp(word, "hello") != 0) {
    system("clear");
    printf("\nSay hello to me : ");
    // insure buffered output is flushed
    fflush(stdout);

    // Avoid magic numbers, use `sizeof  word`
    // Test if input was received
    if (fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "\nInput closed\n");
      return 1;
    }

    // lop off potential trailing \n
    word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';
  }

  printf("congrats, you made it !\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

You don't need the space in the `scanf` format string.  The `%s` format specifier already ignores leading whitespace.  So instead of `" %s"` use `"%s"`.

The main problem is `word != "hello"`.  That's not how strings are compared.  What you're actually doing is comparing the address of `word` with the address of the string constant `"hello"`.  To do a string comparison, use `strcmp`.  If it returns 0, the strings are the same, so your `while` loop should check for non-zero:

```
while (strcmp(word,"hello")) {
```

Be sure to `#include <string.h>` to get the declaration of `strcmp`.

Finally, you need to initialize `word` so that the initial string comparison doesn't invoke undefined behavior by reading uninitialized data:

```
char word[100] = {0};
```

Comment: scanf is a bad idea, for interactive sessions you want to read a line.

Comment: took notes thanks. I was actually rushing into that enter key problem and so I forgot all my manners :)